# Number of trees for a given number of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

The title says it all. Formally, given `n`, the number of **unlabelled** nodes, how many distinct (considering isomorphic graphs to be same) undirected trees can be constructed?

(Was struck by this thought, and could not find any answer on the internet.)

Comment: Are the tree arbitrary, n-ary, rooted, labeled, planar, directed, etc. This matters.

Comment: @GuyCoder, as mentioned the only constraint is that the trees are undirected. Nothing else.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000055